# Exported animation from Blender to UE4 is inside floor

Tags: animation, export, transforms, unreal-engine

I use plugin "Mr Mannequins Tools" to generate full rigged mannequin from UE4, but after exporting some animations(without mesh), it shows them in floor. It seems it has problem only with another compatible skeleton.
Do you know where can be a problem?
[image]

[image]

[image][image]